# Нужна ли запятая после "этот"?

Tags: пунктуация

Этот 2015 год знаменательный для Вас и для Вашей компании.

Comment: Всё предложение звучит странно, возможно, из-за отсутствия сказуемого.

Answer (score 4):

Для придания предложению законченности можно прилагательное перевести в краткую форму; "этот" стилистически лучше заменить на "нынешний".

```
Нынешний 2015 год знаменателен для Вас и для Вашей компании.
```

Прилагательное "нынешний" и порядковое числительное "2015" указывают на временное положение года - относительно текущего момента и относительно Рождества. Их можно было бы отнести к однородным определениям (с запятой между ними), однако формально разные части речи к таковым не принято относить. Поэтому придётся обойтись без запятой.

Comment: А как, по-Вашему, надо оформить исходное предложение, хоть оно и не очень хорошее? Со словом "этот" "2015 год" является пояснением или нет?

Comment: "Этот" несёт ту же функцию, что и "нынешний", поскольку тоже имеет значение "текущего" года (указывает не просто на "какой-то" год). Но совместно с другими определениями "этот" не очень хорошо сочетается, больше подходит в качестве единственного указания на год. Уточнения здесь нет, поскольку, определив год одним способом, точности определения времени вторым способом не повысить. Запятой не должно быть по той же причине, что в изменённом варианте.

Comment: Я в другом комментарии уже писал, что "этот год" можно понимать не только как календарный, но и период в данный момент с 1 октября 2014 года до сих пор. Или это только я так могу понять, а все остальные воспринимают его **только** как календарный?

Comment: Именно как календарный все его себе и представляют, даже если в конце года так сказать. А вообще, "этот" настолько плохо сочетается с 2015, что можно представить себе их удачное сочетание разве что в другом значении (напр. "этот /пресловутый/ 2015 год был просто ужасен." ср. Ах, эта красная рябина)

Comment: Всё-таки скажите, согласны Вы со вторым моим трактованием года или нет? Независимо от знаков препинания.

Comment: Я могу так назвать только текущий год.

Comment: Да, пожалуй, я с Вами согласен. Я так же.

Answer (score 1):

> Нужна ли запятая после “этот”?

Запятая не нужна. Нужно тире после слова "год":

*Этот 2015 год -- знаменательный для Вас и для Вашей компании.*

Comment: Тире, как правило, не ставится, если сказуемое выражено прилагательным. Но может ставиться как исключение. Д. Э. Розенталь. Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке.

Comment: По-моему, в Вашем предложении более уместна краткая форма прилагательного - "знаменателен".

Comment: _Матвей Дёмин: ...в Вашем предложении..._ === Да предложение-то не моё. Моё в нём только тире.

Comment: Извините, Слава, я не спец писать комментарии. Этот я пользователю Alenka хотел адресовать.

Comment: Я поняла, спасибо. Вы, наверное, правы. Тире смотрится лучше, если оставить полное прилагательное, если сделать краткое, то оно будет лишним.

Answer (score 1):

Грамотнее будет без "этот". *2015 год знаменателен для Вас и для Вашей компании* или *Этот год знаменателен для Вас и для Вашей компании.* Если оставить предложенный Вами вариант, то *2015* придётся выделять запятыми с обеих сторон.

Comment: Матвей, а на основании чего ставить запятую здесь?

Comment: Между подлежащим и сказуемым на месте связки ставится тире, а не запятая.

Comment: 2015 год и так "этот", а не "другой". Слово "этот" здесь не нужно. Если его (не знаю, для чего) всё-таки оставить, то "2015" выглядит как уточнение, которое нужно выделить запятыми. Но оставлять предложение в предложенном виде просто не нужно, оно безграмотно.

Comment: Так иногда говорят, когда хотят сказать "этот", но не уверены, что собеседник правильно поймёт, и поэтому уточняют. Можно ведь понять год как период с то же числа год назад до сих пор. А просто "2015 год" может звучать сухо, поэтому может не хотеться так сказать. Всё imho.

Comment: Матвей, никакого уточнение здесь нет. Что здесь уточняется? Уточняющий член должен отвечать на тот же вопрос, что и другой член, после которого он стоит, и служащий для уточнения (обычно он сужает объем понятия, выражаемого уточняемым членом).

Comment: Точно, это не уточнение, а пояснение.

Comment: Да, мне тоже кажется, что слово "этот" - просто лишнее.

Comment: Artyom Lugovoy, а если это пояснение, то запятыми оно выделяется?

Comment: Мне кажется да, а Вам? Вроде обособляются всегда и уточняющие, и поясняющие обороты, нет?

Comment: Если оставить "этот", то 2015 выглядит как уточнение или пояснение, и запятые сами напрашиваются.

Comment: Здесь нет ни пояснения, ни уточнения. Пояснительные члены предложения равнозначны поясняемым, но называют их по-другому. Они являются вторыми наименованиями по отношению к первым, поясняемым, которые выражают то или иное понятие недостаточно определенно или по каким-то причинам недостаточно понятно. Эти члены предложения обычно имеют указание на их пояснительный характер, т. е. сопровождаются специальными союзами: то есть, именно, а именно, или в значении «то есть»:

Comment: Нее, мы говорим про случаи без этих союзов.